# Win11: I tried to remove WSL and Ubuntu but now terminal launches with an Error

Tags: powershell, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Steps I took**:
Remove Ubuntu by uninstalling it via Microsoft store.
Uninstalled the WSL and even the Hyper-V feature.
I removed Ubuntu's profile from the Terminal settings page and verified it's missing from the settings.json

**What was I doing?**:
I was trying to add Git-Bash.exe to the profile options of Terminal in Windows 11. (unsuccessful)

**Problem I'm having**:
Whenever I launch terminal, it launches into a tab titled "Ubuntu" (with the linux icon and all).  It looks like wsl failed to run, the help page is showing.
The error at the end of the page reads:

`[process exited with code 1 (0x00000001)]`

**My Question**:

Not only how do I stop this from happening but where are Windows' instructions to run WSL coming from?
[image: Picture of terminal at launch]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu must have been stuck as the default terminal profile somehow.

I changed the 'When Terminal Starts' setting (in terminal settings) to 'Open a window from the previous session' as opposed to 'launch default profile'. The problem went away.

Then I changed the 'When Terminal Starts' setting back to my preferred profile.

Comment: Good to see you managed to fix the problem. However this is a bit unclear. To make this useful for the future generations, could you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771718/edit) the question and clarify where exactly you changed this? Screenshots would also be a very useful addition. You can't add them to the answer yet, but just upload them to imgur or similar and add the links. Someone will put them in for you :-) Also you really should clarify what you mean by Ubuntu being stuck as a default editor - an operating system can't be an editor.

Answer (score -1):

Removing Docker Desktop and restarting Windows fixed the issue for me.

WSL: 1.2.5.0
Docker Desktop: 4.19.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).